# How to implement a ratelimit across mutiple coroutines efficently?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

So let's say I have a bunch of couroutines running that interact with some webservice and since I don't want to spam it I wanna limit the requests to 1 request every x seconds max. For that I could use some code like this:

```
fun CoroutineScope.rateLimiter(tokens: SendChannel<Unit>, rate: Int) = launch {
    var lastToken = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while (isActive) {
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - lastToken < rate) {
            delay(currentTime - lastToken)
        }
        tokens.send(Unit)
    }
}

fun CoroutineScope.request(tokens: ReceiveChannel<Unit>) = launch { 
    for (token in tokens) {
        //Do Web request
    }
}
```

1.) Is this way to do that efficient?

2.) This isn't expandable to say limit something to x bytes/second or something where I would need to request x tokens out of a [Token Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket), what would be the best way to implement something like that with coroutines?

Comment: Conceptually, it feels like one could extend this idea pretty easily to a token-bucket thing - if you keep track of the last time an input event occurred, then you can calculate on the fly how many tokens have accumulated in the mean-time, and thus whether to forward the packet.

Comment: I'm not sure I can quite follow, I mean sure I can send a message to the channel with how many tokens are available in total right now, but that dosen't mean I will use all of them then I'd have to send the unused tokens back and if in the meantime another coroutine asked for tokens it would not get any.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna skip having dependency on jobs and channels that might create more permits than are being consumed, and then having a stampeeding herd once some process starts taking permits, maybe this is the solution for you.

(Some jvm-style in here, but replaceable for Multi-platform)

```
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock

class SimpleRateLimiter(eventsPerSecond: Double) {

    private val mutex = Mutex()

    @Volatile
    private var next: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE
    private val delayNanos: Long = (1_000_000_000L / eventsPerSecond).toLong()

    /**
     * Suspend the current coroutine until it's calculated time of exit
     * from the rate limiter
     */
    suspend fun acquire() {
        val now: Long = System.nanoTime()
        val until = mutex.withLock {
            max(next, now).also {
                next = it + delayNanos
            }
        }
        if (until != now) {
            delay((until - now) / 1_000_000)
        }
    }
}
```

It ofc comes with other tradeoffs.

- Behavior when nanoTime is nearing Long.MAX_VALUE is most definitely corrupted.
- No impl for maxDelay/timeout
- No way of grabbing multiple termits
- No tryAquire implementation

If you want an IntervalLimiter that allows X requests every Y seconds, and then throws exceptions, there is the [RateLimiter in Resilience4J](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter)
Or if you want something that is a lot more fully featured, I'm working on a  [PR to create both a RateLimiter and an IntervalLimiter in coroutines core project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/2799).

Answer (score 0):

(Hello from [feature request Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#460](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/460)!)
Here's the rate limiter I'm putting in my internal kitchen sink library. Simple*, multiplatform, no extra deps:

```kotlin
public fun <T> rateLimiter(resource: T, minDelay: Duration): Flow<T>
    = flow {
        while (true) {
            emit(resource)
            delay(minDelay)
        }
    }.conflate()
```

Usage:

```
val endpoints = listOf("dokka", "kotlinx.coroutines", "kotlinx.serialization").map { "https://api.github.com/repos/Kotlin/$it/events" }
val responses = rateLimiter(HttpClient(), 500.milliseconds).associateWithEach(endpoints)
    .map { (httpClient, uri) -> httpClient.get(uri).body<String>().also { println(it.length) } }
    .toList()
println("got ${responses.size} responses")

// * and the asterisk: I don't think `rateLimiter` is useful unless paired with the not-so-simple `associateWithEach` extension, which looks like this:
public fun <C, T> Flow<C>.associateWithEach(iterable: Iterable<T>): Flow<Pair<C, T>>
    = iterable.iterator().let { iter ->
        this.transformWhile { recvElem ->
            if (iter.hasNext()) emit(Pair(recvElem, iter.next()))
            iter.hasNext()
        }
    }
```